# How Moment.js can convert UTC time to local time at client side

Tags: datetime, momentjs

just see the code first

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("[data-utc-time]").text(function () {
    var utcTime = $(this).attr("data-utc-time");
    return moment.utc(utcTime, 'DD.MM.YYYY HH:mm').local().format('DD.MM.YYYY HH:mm');
});
```

specially see this line `moment.utc(utcTime, 'DD.MM.YYYY HH:mm').local().format('DD.MM.YYYY HH:mm');`

i like to know for what basis Moment library convert UTC Time to local time?

how moment will know client is from which time zone area ?

can shade some light on it. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's running on the client, and thus understands the client's local time.  Internally it uses the JavaScript `Date` object to achieve that, which has local time behavior.

Comment: does it mean it has no relation with timezone ? i guess when UTC time need to convert to local time then timezone need to be consider....am i right?

Comment: if moment rely on client local time then a error may occur if client pc has wrong time set. how could i use moment.js as a result it should calculate right time based on timezone if client has wrong time set. is it possible?

Comment: Yes, it does run on the client, and thus relies on the client having the correct time zone set.  If you don't want to rely on the client-side time zone data, then you'd need to use the [moment-timezone add-on](http://momentjs.com/timezone/).  Of course then you would need to know what specific time zone you actually wanted to work with.

Comment: if moment has inbuilt feature for timezone then i guess we do not have to depend on this library `http://pellepim.bitbucket.org/jstz/` am i right?

Comment: @Thomas - moment-timezone doesn't yet have the jstz functionality, but we're working on that.  Your original question was just about manipulating values in the local zone, not detecting it with a named identifier.